# Threads, spawn regularly VS. trap in infinite temporised loop?

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, pthreads

This isn't a technical question, but a conceptual one. My program needs to handle several tasks in background. In my case, I consider threads more appropriate than processes for several reasons :

- Background tasks aren't heavy, but they have to be processed regularly.
- All threads need to manipulate a shared resource. Complete processes would require setting up a shared memory segment, which isn't appropriate in my case (the resource doesn't have a fixed size). Of course, this resource is protected by a mutex.

Another thing I take into consideration is that the `main()` function needs to be able to end all backgrounds tasks when it wants to (which means joining threads).

Now, here are two implementations :

### 1 thread, looping inside.

```
void *my_thread_func(void* shared_ressource)
{
    while(1){
        do_the_job();
        sleep(5);
    }
}

// main()
pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, my_thread_func, (void*)&shared_ressource);
pthread_kill(my_thread, 15); 
// pthread_cancel(my_thread);
pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);
```

*Note* : In this case, `main()` needs to signal (or cancel) the thread before joining, otherwise it'll hang. This can be dangerous if the thread doesn't get time to `sem_post` before it gets terminated.

### n threads, looping outside.

```
void *my_thread_func(void* shared_ressource)
{
    do_the_job();
}

// main()
while(1){
    pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, my_thread_func, (void*)&shared_ressource);
    pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);
    sleep(5);
}
```

*Note* : In this case, `main()` wouldn't naturally hang on `pthread_join`, it would just have to kill its own continuous loop (using a "boolean" for instance).

Now, I would like some help comparing those two. Threads are lightweight structures, but is the spawning process too heavy for the second implementation ? Or is the infinite loop *holding* the thread when it shouldn't ? At the moment, I prefer the second implementation because it protects the semaphore : threads do not terminate before they `sem_post` it. My concern here is optimisation, not functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your background threads continuously spawning and dying tends to be inefficient.  It is usually much better to have some number of threads stay alive, servicing the background work as it becomes available.

However, it's often better to avoid thread cancellation, too.  Instead, I advise using a condition variable and exit flag:

```
void *my_thread_func(void *shared_resource)
{
    struct timespec timeout;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&exit_mutex);

    do
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&exit_mutex);
        do_the_job();

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
        timeout.tv_sec += 5;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&exit_mutex);
        if (!exit_flag)
            pthread_cond_timedwait(&exit_cond, &exit_mutex, &timeout);
    } while (!exit_flag)

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&exit_mutex);
}
```

When the main thread wants the background thread to exit, it sets the exit flag and signals the condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&exit_mutex);
exit_flag = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&exit_cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&exit_mutex);
pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);
```

(You should actually strongly consider using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of the default `CLOCK_REALTIME`, because the former isn't affected by changes to the system clock.  This requires using `pthread_condattr_setclock()` and `pthread_cond_init()` to set the clock used by the condition variable.)

Comment: I like the idea, yet I don't understand why you use a global exit flag **and** an exit condition. When `main` calls `pthread_cond_signal`, the thread *knows* it has to stop, because otherwise `pthread_cond_timedwait` would return ETIMEDOUT. Couldn't we just loop on the result of `pthread_cond_timedwait` (while == ETIMEDOUT) ?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: Consider what would happen if the main thread signalled the condition variable while the background thread was executing `do_the_job()`.  In addition, `pthread_cond_timedwait()` is allowed to wake up early (returning 0) even if the condition wasn't signalled - this is known as a "spurious wakeup".  Condition variables always need to be paired with a condition to check - in this case, the condition is just the state of the `exit_flag`.

Comment: Got it, I accepted. Thanks a lot, that's probably the solution I'll implement.